Selenium Error: Chrome Fails to Start After Crawling Many Records
Hoping to find my answers here. I'm using Selenium with Python to crawl data, but after about 2,500 records out of say 50,000, I encounter this error and my ECS Fargate instance terminates:
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Here's the relevant traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 292, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

Here is what my task definition looks like:
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [],
            "essential": true,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "systemControls": []
        }
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "revision": 12,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "cpu": "2048",
    "memory": "4096",
    "tags": []
}

